# Como ler retorno de uma função java

Tags: javascript, java, web-service, jax-ws, rhino

Utilizo uma plataforma ged de terceiros que disponibiliza `web-services` `JAX-WS`. Existe um método chamado `getInstanceCardData que retorna o valor dos campos do registro de formulário de uma solicitação.
Segue a assinatura do método:

**Método:**

> getInstanceCardData(String user, String password, int companyId,
>   String userId, int processInstanceId)

**Parâmetros:**

1. user: login do usuário
2. password: senha do usuário.
3. companyId: código da empresa.
4. userId: matrícula do usuário.
5. processInstanceId: número da solicitação.

> *Retorno: String[][].*

Ao **chamar o método** tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
net.java.dev.jaxb.array.StringArrayArray@3cece078
```

Não estou conseguindo acessar os dados do retorno.
Só consigo acessar uma informação.
Veja:

```
result = getInstanceCardData(user, pass, company, userId, numeroProcesso);
var item = getInstanceCardData.getItem();
newDataset.addRow([
        item[i].item, // So consigo acessar essa informação.
        //item[i++].item
        //item[i++].item[i++]
        //item[i].item.item nem roda
       ]);
```

**Abaixo segue uma imagem do soapUI acessando o método.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala fera!

Acredito que o ws que está usando é do fluig/ECM da TOTVS. Segue exemplo de como obter o retorno, seja em eventos de formulário, processo ou dataset:

```
var result = getInstanceCardData(user, pass, company, userId, numeroProcesso);
var resultAbstract = []

for (int i = 0; i < result.getItem().size(); i++)
    resultAbstract.push({i: result.getItem().get(i).getItem()})

for(i in resultAbstract)
    log.info('Campo ' + i + ' valor ' + resultAbstract[i])
```

A variável resultAbstract serve para abstrair o retorno dos dados. Dessa forma fica mais fácil trabalhar com os mesmos

Comment: Verdade, uso o ECM. Ainda não migramos para Fluig.

Comment: Efetuei um ajuste no código, agora deve estar OK

Comment: Isso que estou fazendo é um dataset customizado.

Comment: sim deve funcionar também

Comment: Não deu certo>
Ocorreu "[Lnet.java.dev.jaxb.array.StringArray;" has no public instance field or method named "get".